# How do I speed up the dropdown showing on the sub menus for the theme Monochrome Pro? Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, slidetoggle

Firstly there is a delay when you hover that I want to remove and then I want to speed up the slide down.

I'm not 100% sure how the code is working, but when you hover the class sfhover gets added to the parent of the element and then the sub-menu class updates, see below:

```
     <li id="menu-item-669" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-669 sfHover">
<a href="https://www.security-audit.com/penetration-testing/" data-ps2id-api="true" itemprop="url" class="sf-with-ul"><span itemprop="name">Penetration Testing <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
    <button class="sub-menu-toggle ionicons-before ion-ios-arrow-down" aria-expanded="false" aria-pressed="false"><span class="screen-reader-text">Submenu</span></button><ul class="sub-menu" style="">
        <li id="menu-item-2907" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2907"><a href="https://www.security-audit.com/website-security-auditing-and-testing/" data-ps2id-api="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Website Penetration Testing</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1817" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1817"><a href="https://www.security-audit.com/network-security-penetration-testing/" data-ps2id-api="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Network Penetration Testing Experts</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1815" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1815"><a href="https://www.security-audit.com/external-network-penetration-testing/" data-ps2id-api="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">External Network Penetration Testing</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1813" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1813"><a href="https://www.security-audit.com/owasp-website-penetration-testing/" data-ps2id-api="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">OWASP Website Penetration Testing Services</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1811" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1811"><a href="https://www.security-audit.com/pci-penetration-testing/" data-ps2id-api="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">PCI Penetration Testing</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
```

I've also found this code in the files, but when I make changes to it nothing happens:

```
/**
 * Action for submenu toggles.
 */
function _submenuToggle() {

    var $this  = $( this ),
        others = $this.closest( '.menu-item' ).siblings();
    _toggleAria( $this, 'aria-pressed' );
    _toggleAria( $this, 'aria-expanded' );
    $this.toggleClass( 'activated' );
    $this.next( '.sub-menu' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );

    others.find( '.' + subMenuButtonClass ).removeClass( 'activated' ).attr( 'aria-pressed', 'false' );
    others.find( '.sub-menu' ).slideUp( 'fast' );

}

/**
 * Activate/deactivate superfish.
 * @params buttons
 */
function _superfishToggle( buttons ) {
    var _superfish = $( '.' + responsiveMenuClass + ' .js-superfish' ),
        $args      = 'destroy';
    if ( typeof _superfish.superfish !== 'function' ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( 'none' === _getDisplayValue( buttons ) ) {
        $args = {
            'delay': 0,
            'animation': {'opacity': 'show', 'height': 'show'},
            'dropShadows': false,
            'speed': 'fast',
            'speedOut': 'fast',
        };
    }
    _superfish.superfish( $args );
}
```

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Looks like this was using the "Superfish" menu script, so you should go and check what options this offers, https://superfish.joelbirch.design